# How to safely bind HTML from Model to View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngsanitize

### Show html code as html code if all text and styles are saved on api

Let's say i'm using a text editor and i save on an api not only the text, but the html styles too (ex. `<align>`, `<h1>`, blabla). What i want is to show the text on my html view, but using the styles. Per example, if i've saved `<h1><u>Hello there!</u><h1>`, i need to show on my html view the text as title h1 and underlined.

My code to get the api response:

```
function info(){
        $http.get('/theApi')
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.product = data.data.Response;
        });
    }
```

Returns something like this:

```
[{Name: "Chuck", Message: "<h1><u>Hello there!</u><h1>"}]
```

If i pass the data like this:

```
{{product.Message}}
```

On my html view i'll get, literally:

```
<h1><u>Hello there!</u><h1>
```

So, what can i do to get the text as a title h1 and undderlined on the html view?

I'm using AnguarJs and Javascript.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: This is a common question. http://www.saintsatplay.com/blog/2015/02/parsing-html-data-from-an-array-inside-an-angularjs-view#.Wuy066gvxhE

Comment: Wrap it inside <code> tag.

Comment: Angular is sanitizing your HTML. There's plenty of docs on how to make it not do that.

Comment: Use ngBindHtml with $sanitize : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: Be careful. Using HTML for styling is a misuse of the language. Set the alignment or underlining via CSS instead. (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ng-bind-html` directive with the [ngSanitize module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize):

```js
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myHTML =
       '<h1><u>Hello there!</u><h1>';
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<body ng-app="bindHtmlExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input ng-model="myHTML">
  <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</body>
```

For more information, [AngularJS ng-bind-html Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).